# Postman gives a success response while the same API throws error when called through angular code

Tags: angular, api, observable, postman

I'm getting some info from API. All the postman calls are success. Please find the attachment below.

[image]

**When I call the same API in my angular application, I'm getting below error from back-end.**

[image]

[image]

Component file

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getOffers();
  }

  getOffers(){     
    this._offerService.getOffers()
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                  if (data.CODE == 401){
                    console.log("Session not valid");
                  }
                  this.offers = <Offers[]>data;
                  console.log("offers response ",data);

                },
                error => {
                  console.log("An Error Occurred ", error);
                });
  }
```

Service File :

```
getOffers(): Observable<any>{
    const token = this.authService.getToken();
    console.log("Offer to ", token);

    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
    });
    let options = { headers: headerOptions };

    const url = environment.baseURL + 'promotions';

    return this._http.get<any>(url, options)
      .pipe(map(offers => {
        return offers;
      }));

  }
```

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you debug your api code ? Did you api call reach your backend code ?

Comment: @TonyNgo I did, actually they are receiving the bearer token. Seems like session is not creating for requests from my angular applications, but session is successfully created for all the calls in PostMan

Comment: I feel it is wrong with the authorization. Try sending token same as you are sending in postman and check it out if the response is true

Comment: @MaruthiEranki When I hardcoded the token from PostMan in angular code, still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you post the API code which is handling the request?

Comment: @Showy I don't have access to back-end code. Since every postman request is getting succeeded, Do you think that it is something to do with the back-end ?

Comment: Yes I think, I'll explain it in an answer

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @Showy No, not yet. We had to disable the sessions in back-end. After doing that, it works perfectly. Therefore, we presume it's something to do with the back-end.

Answer (score 2):

This **could be an allowed hosts problem**, since angular sends requests from a different port of your address.

Let me explain better:

In backend code there could be an **allowed hosts setting** which allows or handles requests from **192.168.1.4** (which postman may use to send requests) but not **192.168.1.4:4200** (which angular uses to send requests)

And the **response error may differ** if handled by backend code